# Uno platform: load xaml image from Assets

Tags: image, icons, uno-platform

For the Uno platform, I would like to load an image (PNG) from Assets, using XAML. Further, I'd like to use a single image for all target platforms and have it scale to the size of its container.

Is this possible ?

I have succeeded to do this for UWP and Wasm with the following syntax:

```
<Image Source="Assets/icons/arrow_back_white.png" />
```

However, for Android, no image is displayed, I just see my background color.

I realize that the proper approach is to provide separate images for each target platform and, optionally, separate images for each resolution in each platform. That is a nice ideal but I am trying to avoid that enormous development overhead, at least for now.

Thanks.

EDIT:

First, to be extra clear, I do have `Content` selected for my images.

I'm getting a worse failure when using `AppBarButton`, e.g.:

```
<CommandBar>
  <AppBarButton Icon="arrow_back_white.png" Label="Back" Click="OnBackClicked" />
  <AppBarButton Icon="arrow_back_white.png" Label="Page" Click="OnPageClicked" />
  <AppBarButton Icon="more_menu_white.png" Label="More" Click="OnMoreMenuClicked"/>
</CommandBar>
```

This fails for UWP during app initialization with an error:

```
Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IconElement' from the text 'arrow_back_white.png'.
```

It also fails with a build error for Wasm and Android.

It doesn't matter if I put the icon files directly in the Assets directory or a nested directory.

What is the correct syntax and configuration to reference icons and images ?

EDIT 2:

Still doesn't work for Android, but does work for UWP and Wasl. I moved my images into the Assets directory and have this XAML:

```
  <Button
    Width="25" Height="25"
    Padding="5" 
    Click="OnBackClicked" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/arrow_back_white.png" Height="100" Width="100" />
  </Button>

  <Button
    Width="25" Height="25"
    Padding="5"
    Click="OnPageClicked" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/crop_din_white.png" />
  </Button>

  <Button
    Width="25" Height="25"
    Padding="5" 
    Click="OnMoreMenuClicked" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/more_menu_white.png" />
  </Button>
```

All three buttons show up as blank grey approx 1cm high and wide.

EDIT 3

Tried with a newly created default app, which works. The only change I made to the code is to MainPage.xaml by removing the grid and adding:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >

  <Button
    Width="25" Height="25"
    Padding="5" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/arrow_back_white.png" Height="100" Width="100" />
  </Button>

  <Button
    Width="25" Height="25"
    Padding="5" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/crop_din_white.png" />
  </Button>

  <Button
    Width="25" Height="25"
    Padding="5" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/more_menu_white.png" />
  </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

So, now, the arduous task of finding the significant difference(s).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a Directory under the Shared Project called `Assets` and inside you have an image called wasm_logo.png.

[image]

As Jt6 indicated you should be able to use that image for all the different platforms Uno supports, including Android by using this:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/wasm_logo.png" Height="300" Width="300"/>
```

Note: If you have a nested Directory, another directory inside Assets, you just need to add it as part of the path.

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/wasm_logo.png" Height="300" Width="300"/>
```

The code above will work if your **wasm_logo.png** image is inside an **Icons** Directory which is inside the **Assets** directory.

Considerations:

- Images should be marked as Content (you already validated this)

To Scale for different sizes Uno Supports (as UWP) different Assets qualifiers. Let's say that the same image you want to support 3 different sizes, then you would these 3 files inside the Assets Directory:

```
wasm_logo.scale-100.png
wasm_logo.scale-300.png
wasm_logo.scale-500.png
```

For Android these are translated into **mdpi**, **xhdpi** and **xxhdpi**. But the best part is that to use it you do not need to specify the size and with the same code as above you will get the same result.

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/wasm_logo.png" Height="300" Width="300"/>
```

**Note**: For Android when you do not specify any qualifier the Images is treated as [nodpi](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp)

More about Assets and qualifiers can be read [here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/working-with-assets.html).

If the above is still not working try updating your Uno.Platform to the latest version.

You could also validate that no errors are being reported on the Visual Studio Output Window when running the app.

As a final thing, you could try checking if the images are being moved correctly at compile time. You can do this by building your Android project and then opening the File Explorer at this route:

```
ProjectName\ProjectName.Droid\obj\Debug\100\res
```

Inside there you should find the Drawable Directories for Android.

[image]

Following the first example, your image should be in the Drawable-nodpi folder

[image]

Hope this is useful.

Andres

**App Runining**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I'm blocked right now on a build problem for the android head. I will say, though, that I had tried the ms-appx syntax earlier, and that didn't work, either, for android.

Comment: Still doesn't work. See EDIT 2 in the my post, please.

Comment: I tried again, this time creating a fresh app. The only changes I made to the solution was to remove some of the heads. Still doesn't display images in Android. See EDIT 3.

Comment: Never mind. I forgot to copy the images to my fresh app. It works in the fresh app, so now I will look for differences.

Comment: Make sure that your images in the shared project have the `Content` build type.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and here is how I resolved it.  I used the following:
`<Image Source="ms-appx:////Assests/yourimage.png">`
The other thing I did- you probably have done this already- but I had to put a transparent border around it.  Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately, this still doesn't work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that did not help.  Just checking something obvious- did you add the picture to the Shared Project Assets folder?

Comment: Bear in mind that I stated the code works for UWP and Wasm.